# PHP MySQLi select function not execute

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to call my function, but she's wrong.
I believe it is in connection variable.

**Connection:**

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('','','', '');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   header("Location: error.php");
   exit();
}
```

**Function:**

```
function t_car($id) {

  global $conn;

  $s_t_car = "SELECT *
             FROM t_car
             WHERE session='$id'";

  $s_t_car_return = mysqli_query($conn, $s_t_car) or die("Erro SQL.".mysqli_error());

  return $s_t_car_return;

}
```

**Call Function:**

```
$s_t_car_return = t_car($conn, $_SESSION['session_client']);

if(mysqli_num_rows($s_t_car_return )!=0) {

   while($r_t_car = mysqli_fetch_array($s_t_car_return )) {

   }

}
```

**Error:**

Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Comment: Where are you getting that error? A couple of other points - you ` return $s_t_carrinhos_return`, but `$s_t_carrinhos_return` is never actually defined; is that a typo? Also, `mysqli_error()` takes the connection as a parameter, so it should be `mysqli_error($conn)`

Comment: I corrected the variable's return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you need to enter your settings from your MySQL server (mysql db).

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("HOSTNAME","USERNAME", "PASSWORD","DATABASE");
```

You can then use an if statement to check if the connection to the server has been made, if so, continue execution of following code, otherwise die();

If you want to fetch the data see below here:

```
$res = $connection->query("SELECT finger FROM hand WHERE index = 3");
while($row = $res->fetch_array())
{
     print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for that, made a typo.

Comment: I could not call the function in the way that I wrote?

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_query()` returns a result. You have to fetch the result to do something with it.

```
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $s_t_car) or die("...");
$s_t_car_return = mysqli_fetch_row($res);
```

Comment: I could not call the function in the way that I wrote?